# What is the BOOL *stop argument for enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: used for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, enumeration, fast-enumeration

I've been using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` a lot lately for my fast-enumeration needs, and I'm having a hard time understanding the usage of `BOOL *stop` in the enumeration block.

The `NSArray` class reference states

> `stop`: A reference to a Boolean value. The block can set the value to `YES` to
>   stop further processing of the array. The `stop` argument is an out-only
>   argument. You should only ever set this Boolean to `YES` within the
>   Block.

So then of course I can add the following in my block to stop the enumeration:

```
if (idx == [myArray indexOfObject:[myArray lastObject]]) {
    *stop = YES;
}
```

From what I've been able to tell, not explicitly setting `*stop` to `YES` doesn't have any negative side effects. The enumeration seems to automatically stop itself at the end of the array. So is using `*stop` really necessary in a block?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The `stop` argument to the Block allows you to stop the enumeration *prematurely*. It's the equivalent of `break` from a normal `for` loop. You can ignore it if you want to go through every object in the array.

```
for( id obj in arr ){
    if( [obj isContagious] ){
        break;    // Stop enumerating
    }

    if( ![obj isKindOfClass:[Perefrigia class]] ){
        continue;    // Skip this object
    }

    [obj immanetizeTheEschaton];
}
```

---

```
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if( [obj isContagious] ){
        *stop = YES;    // Stop enumerating
        return;
    }

    if( ![obj isKindOfClass:[Perefrigia class]] ){
        return;    // Skip this object
    }

    [obj immanentizeTheEschaton];
}];
```

That is an out parameter because it is a reference to a variable from the calling scope. It needs to be set inside your Block, but read inside of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, the same way `NSError`s are commonly passed back to your code from framework calls.

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block {
    // N.B: This is probably not how this method is actually implemented!
    // It is just to demonstrate how the out parameter operates!

    NSUInteger idx = 0;
    for( id obj in self ){

        BOOL stop = NO;

        block(obj, idx++, &stop);

        if( stop ){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `stop` flag is advisory;  the enumeration may continue for some undefined number of iterations in the concurrent case, for example.   I.e. you shouldn't set an `__block` variable unconditionally on each pass through the enumeration and expect it to be the "last" value when using `stop` to early terminate.  You should always couple the "no, use this object" with setting `stop = YES;`.

Comment: @bbum, can you clarify whether the continuing behavior applies _only_ to concurrent enumeration? While it's perfectly understandable in that case, it isn't documented, and would be quite a surprising bite in the ass for "serial" enumeration.

Comment: <rdar://problem/15015199> now asks for clarification as the documentation doesn't say either way and it should.