# Accessing Properties of Objects in Array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm pretty new to programming, and am a little caught up in what to do. Now, each of the objects in my NSArray has its own properties containing data in which I need.  I'm used to iterating through an array to access it's objects, but have never had to iterate through one and access the properties of some of its objects. So I am completely lost.

Usually when I need to iterate through an array, it's a straightforward process, something like:

```
For (int i =0; i <= self.array.count; i++) {
NSLog(@"%d", i):
}
```

Easy enough. But, now I'm faced with the challenge of  looking into the all jacked stored in the arrays index, and access a piece of information from that given object. I need to do this and a for loop since there are multiple objects.  I believe from what I've read on this website that I have the logic behind it correct, but I am unsure of how to access the object's properties rather than just the object itself.

Comment: How would you access the properties of an object if you weren't iterating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= self.array.count; i++) {
    // ... inside the loop ...
}
```

...then when you are inside the loop, each object in the array can be obtained, one per iteration, as `[self.array objectAtIndex:i]`. So fetch that. *Now you have one of your objects!*

Now just access any property of that object you like. You will probably want to *cast* to the correct *type* of that object, so that the compiler understands what sort of object this is and will allow you to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Objective-C has a more compact way of iterating through an NSArray, as Josh rightly points out, but I used your notation so as to start in the place where you have started.

Comment: The cast remark is an important point, since you can't use dot notation on an `id`, which is the return type of `objectAtIndex:`

Answer (score 1):

Use [fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW1) instead of iteration by index, and then access the property as usual.

```
for( id obj in myArray ){    // Use a more specific type than id if possible
    NSLog(@"%@", [obj prop]);
}
```

Another option is to use [Block-based enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW3). There, you will write a Block one of whose arguments is an object from your array. (The objects are presented to the Block in order.)

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop){
    NSLog(@"%@", [obj prop]);
}];
```

In this case, you also have access to the index if you need it for some reason. The [`stop` argument allows early termination of the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12357955/) if you need that.